# Vuejs and laravel -NaN value?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nan, laravel-6

I want to recover a variable from controller and show it but its Show NaN instead of the value.
The idea is to claculate the the progress of my projects in function call progress in my  controller and than show it in table in my Html code.
This is my function in controller and it return the correct value:

```
public function progress($id){

   $tasks=Task::where(['projet_id'=>$id])->get();
   $x=0;
   $i=0;
    foreach ($tasks as $task) {

        $x = $x + $task->progress;
        $i++ ;
     }
     $progress=$x/$i;
     return $progress;
}
```

and this where i want to show the progress in project.vue:

```
    <tr v-for="projet in projets.data" :key="projet.id" >
    <td @change="avancemant(projet.id)">
    {{ parseInt(100 * progress ) }}%
    <img :src="`/img/icon/verif.png`" style="width:15px; 
     v-if="`${parseInt(100*progress)}`==100" >
    </img>
    <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0"   
    id="progress" v-model="form.progress" 
    aria-valuemin="`${parseInt(100*task.progress)}`":style=" 
    {'width':`${parseInt(100*progress)}%`}" aria-valuemax="100">
     </div>
     </div>             
     </td>
```

and this is my project.vue script:

```
  export default {
         data(){
             return{
          progress:'',
          projets:{},
          projet:{
              id:''
          },
          }}
        created(){
        this.avancement(this.projet.id);
        }
        methods:{
         avancemant($id){
           axios.get('/api/progress/'+$id).then(({data})=>(this.progress =data.data));;
         },
        }
```

P.S : it show me in NaN%

Comment: What you have in `this.progress` in Vue? Can you provide the value of variable?

Comment: Start to debug this by console logging `this.progress` after the get. Or look in the network tab in the developer console to see what the value is. I suspect you are getting wrong data from your api.

Comment: in vue it undefined

Comment: @SølveTornøe the problem is not from data api because when i try tp put 1 as as the projet.id in the function avancemant  in created section it work

Comment: Ok, are you sure all projects in `projets.data` has an valid id for your api?
I really reccomend you checking out the network tab and inspect the call making you get `NaN`.

Comment: yes   Sølve Tornøe but i think the issue in   created(){
        this.avancement(this.projet.id);
        }
but  can find it

Comment: I don't believe your route is returning json with progress wrapped in a data attribute, try this as your axios callback `this.progress = data`

Answer (score 1):

In your created function, you tell vue to run the functioin `this.avancement` with a parameter of `this.projet.id`. Since you setup your data object to be the following:

```
data() {
  return {
    progress:'',
    projets:{},
    projet:{
      id:''
    },
  }
}
```

This means that when your code executes the code inside the created hook, it will use the current state of your data.

```
created(){
  this.avancement(this.projet.id); // this.projet.id's value at this point is '' (empty string)
}
```

So when your function then runs the http request, you are sending this:

```
axios.get('/api/progress/'+'').then(({data})=>(this.progress =data.data));
```

This probably breaks your API because it requires an id of some sorts.

At this point, I dont have enough info from your application or goal to know why you run this at created. But a solution to fix this as it is right now would be to add a condition inside your `avancement` function to not run it if the id is not valid.

```
methods:{
  avancemant($id){
   if(isNaN($id)) {
      return
   }
    axios.get('/api/progress/'+$id).then(({data})=>(this.progress =data.data));;
  },
}
```

Comment: Sølve Tornøe you are right there is problem in $id its not passing in the route

Comment: the big problem is in created(){
  this.avancement(this.projet.id);}
any idea how can i fix it??

Comment: I just explained why above. in created, this.projet.id is an empty string..

Comment: any idea that can resolve it or replace it ?
because in created declanche without nowing the projet.id
i try many ways but i fail